# Persisting natural scrolling on a Logitech MX Master 2S in 17.10

Tags: mouse

I have a System76 Gazelle running Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm having trouble setting natural scrolling on a Logitech MX Master 2S. Natural scrolling is enabled in pointer settings, and it works with the laptop's built-in touchpad. Scrolling on the mouse however is reversed and isn't affected by enabling or disabling this setting. With the following command I can enable natural scrolling successfully and it persists until logging out or restarting the computer.

`xinput set-prop "pointer:Logitech MX Master 2S" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1`

I've tried placing this command in various places: .profile, .xsessionrc, and .xinputrc and while I can confirm (with an echo "foo" >> logfile hack) that these files are being sourced on startup and/or login the setting doesn't persist. I suspect something comes along after these Xinit steps and supersedes this setting.

Any ideas on getting this set permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GNOME you can try these:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
```

Comment: Setting them to `true` worked here since I aimed to enable natural scrolling, not disable. Worked like a charm. Thanks!