# Natural Scroll for touchpad in Lubuntu 17.10

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, scrolling

Hi I've recently installed Lubuntu 17.10 on my acer laptop. Very happy overall but there are a few small tweeks I want to make. Something I can't find a way to fix is to set the touchpad to 'reverse' or 'natural' scroll.

synclient VertScrollDelta=-30

works as a temporary fix but trackpad resets on reboot...

Can anyone tell me how to fix this permanently?

Comment: try this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/970723/persisting-natural-scrolling-on-a-logitech-mx-master-2s-in-17-10/970901#970901

Answer (score 0):

1) go to "system settings"

2) click on "mouse & touchpad"

3) check the box saying "Natural Scrolling"

this should fix the problem