# How do I enable natural scrolling on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: touchpad

Earlier, in Ubuntu 16.04, and in Windows 10, I have natural scroll working properly. However, in Ubuntu 17.10, it is not working even though I enabled it in settings. I tried the methods in these questions: [Adaptive acceleration for touchpad on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968516/adaptive-acceleration-for-touchpad-on-ubuntu-17-10) and [Persisting natural scrolling on a Logitech MX Master 2S in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970723/persisting-natural-scrolling-on-a-logitech-mx-master-2s-in-17-10). What do I do?